# php mysql with left outer join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables in mysql table1 and table2

table1 have the following fields

```
Field               Type    

intProjectId        int(11)         
intSourceId     int(11)     
intClientId         int(11)     
varProject      varchar(200)    
fltAmount            float              
varAmountType varchar(50)   
dtStart              date       
dtEnd                date
```

And table 2 have the following fields

```
    Field                                   Type

intPercentageId                     int(11)     
intProjectId                        int(11)         
floatPaymentpercentage              float   
ddDate                              datetime
```

join two table with common project id.If table2 has no records with the particular project id it can joined as null..

Table 1  has project data
Table 2 has its percentage of complettion. (Each project has more than one records. )
Project Id -- common field

Iused the following query

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.intProjectId = table2.intProjectId
GROUP BY table1.varProject ORDER BY table2.intPercentageId DESC
```

Here i get the output as percentage table returns the first record for each project. I need the last inserted record for the table 2.

table1 ==> project id 5 
In table 2 has 3 records for project Id 5. I want to ge the last record from the table2. Now it returns the first record from table 2

How to change the query. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the maximum record for each project in table2 and use that information to get the latest record. Here is a method that uses group by:

```
select t1.*
 from table1 t1 join
 table2 t2
 on t1.intProjectId = t2.intProjectId join
 (select t2.intProjectId, max(intPercentageId) as maxpi
  from table2 t2
  group by t2.intProjectId
 ) tt2
 on t2.intProjectId = tt2.maxpi;
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the maximum record for each project in `table2` and use that information to get the latest record.  Here is a method that uses `group by`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.intProjectId = t2.intProjectId join
     (select t2.intProjectId, max(intPercentageId) as maxpi
      from table2 t2
      group by t2.intProjectId
     ) tt2
     on t2.intProjectId = tt2.maxpi;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.intProjectId = table2.intProjectId
GROUP BY table1.varProject HAVING MAX(table2.intPercentageId)
```

"Order By" runs after "Group by" has completed, that is why it is not giving the intended result. The change I have suggested will give the row from 2nd table with the highest percentage which as per the scenario should be the last row for the project.